# CSS3/HTML5/JS - How can I create an animated texture background with slide effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

You may have seen that in some games there's moving background that goes on diagonal. Take a look at this example of Megaman x Storm Eagle Stage https://youtu.be/Wfm3ZvcxOKQ?t=1m33s, the clouds are moving on from up to bottom, right to left (Diagonal). I need to achieve the same effect using CSS3 or any kind of javascript, with a tile texture.

Where can I find a tutorial teaching how to make that? I found some, but they are for creating dynamic objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this could be solved using basic javascript or any javascript library. I will give a small working example or you can just jump to this js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/lesshardtofind/a2Lx51xy/

In your html you just need one element.

```
<div class='background'></div>
```

The class is for us to select it. First with some css lets make it so we have a picture and can see it.

```
.background{
  background-image: url('yourImageUrl.com/image.png');
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

So background image applies your texture, height, and width will apply values so that you can see the div otherwise it would be 0 with no actual markup inside.

Now for the fun part. JavaScript can grab this div element and apply a style. Normally I would do this in jQuery, but since you just specified javaScript I'll keep external libraries out of it.

```
var x = 0; 
var y = 0;
var xSpeed = 5;
var ySpeed = 5;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  var xVal = x + 'px';
  var yVal = y + 'px';
  var bg = document.getElementsByClassName('background')[0].style.backgroundPosition = xVal + " " + yVal;
  x-=xSpeed;
  y+=ySpeed;
}, 100);
```

To explain this I set `x` and `y` which are my background coordinates to 0 as a start. It is good to set default values otherwise you will invite undefined behavior.  `xSpeed`, and `ySpeed` are just variables you can change the value of speed up or slow down the animation. `interval` is the variable that stores the interval set by the `setInterval` function. `setInterval` accepts a function and a time value as arguments. The function will be called at each interval and the time is the amount of time to wait until calling the function again.

`document.getElementsByClassname('background')` returns an array which I access with the `[0]` index. Then `style` allows you to apply a value to your  `backgroundPosition`. Notice that I applied the 'px' to the end of each number so that they would be a string such as "3px 5px" this is how they are expected.

Then speed is applied using `-=` and `+=`. Since the dom starts at 0, 0 in the left corner of your browser then adding to Y will move down and subtracting from X will move left.

Lastly this works because background is set by default to repeat so the image will continue to just driftdownward and to the left. If you supply a tiled image you won't see the seams in between one repeat and the next.

**Edit: Add fullscreen**

You can add the fullscreen to your child object by making sure that its parents also have a set width and height. So changing your css to.

```
body, html{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.background{
  background-image: url('http://bgfons.com/upload/sky_texture1998.jpg');
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

On `%` heights you need a parent node to inherit height from.

Comment: How can I stretch it to fit horizontal and vertical? I used "100%" in width and height, but I still see some blank spaces.

Comment: I need it on the body.

Comment: Something like `document.body`

Comment: Does jquery use less resources? It's demanding too much from the video board. PS: thx in advance.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you about the resources if I change my interval to `16` which is around 60fps and take a heap snapshot and a cpu profile most of the process is idle. I can't image jQuery animate would be any less.  Possibly velocity if you enable gpu processing.

Comment: Look: http://jsfiddle.net/3tQsc/

You said "On % heights you need a parent node to inherit height from." How do I do that?